# Set Column Width size command not looping through all active worksheets

Tags: excel, vba

Code below executing without error, except line immediately below is **not executing in all active sheets** (probably because line needs to be contained?).

```
Columns("T").ColumnWidth = 50
```

The complete macro is:

```
Sub Resize_Columns_And_Rows_No_Header2()

Dim currentSheet As Worksheet

Set currentSheet = ActiveSheet

Dim sheet As Worksheet

Columns("T").ColumnWidth = 50

For Each sheet In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    With sheet

Columns("T").ColumnWidth = 50

With .Cells.Rows
            .WrapText = True
            .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
            .EntireRow.AutoFit
        End With '.Cells.Rows
        .Columns.EntireColumn.AutoFit
    End With 'sheet
Next sheet

currentSheet.Activate

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that the line `Columns("T").ColumnWidth = 50` within your `With sheet` needs to start with a dot, otherwise it will not be performed on `sheet`.

So change the line within `With sheet` to:

```
.Columns("T").ColumnWidth = 50
```

---

Actually you don't need the `currentSheet` stuff and you don't need to `currentSheet.Activate` in the end because the active sheet never changes running the following code:

```
Public Sub Resize_Columns_And_Rows_No_Header2()
    Dim sheet As Worksheet
    For Each sheet In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        With sheet

            .Columns("T").ColumnWidth = 50

            With .Cells.Rows
                .WrapText = True
                .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
                .EntireRow.AutoFit
            End With '.Cells.Rows

            .Columns.EntireColumn.AutoFit
        End With 'sheet
    Next sheet
End Sub
```

Comment: Perfect! Bravo!